# is it possible to activate usb debugging using adb command line?

Tags: adb, usb-debugging, command-line

i have xiaomi phone and forget mi account. so i try to restore it using factory reset. i try to enabling USB debuging then. but it says "developer option is not avaiable for this user". adb is active. my question is "is it possibe to activate usb debugging using adb command, and how?" thanks

Comment: Can you see your device listed after running `adb devices` command?

Comment: Please add some screenshots.

Comment: yes. my devices is listed on adb devices command. but now i cant get in to my phone. it is locked and ask for activating mi account. maybe i will try to flash it.

Comment: It's chicken or the egg situation. USB Debugging enables you to use Android Debugging Bridge (`adb`). And you want to activate USB Debugging using `adb`.

Answer (score 1):

If the usb debugging is off. Your device won't appear in `adb devices` list.
So you cannot turn it on any other way than opening the developer options and manually enabling it.

Answer (score 0):

YES you can switch on USB debugging through ADB provided you bootlaoder is unlocked. 
Just have to pull few files ---> edit them ---> Push them back.
It is explained on Github:
https://gist.github.com/pantasio/3d0eb4bb03a1e696aae8696f60730859#file-enable-usb-debug-adb

Comment: Since Android 9 `/data/property/persist.sys.usb.config` no more exists. Now there's only one file: `/data/property/persistent_properties`. And that too isn't plain text but includes arbitrary characters. Even after editing that, `adb` authentication won't work without extra steps.